# What is the core file in Docker and can I remove it?

Tags: linux, docker

I got No space left on device warning at my vm and I found that the folder `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` has about 10Gb files. 
I found that there are many large core file inside 
`/var/lib/docker/overlay2/84af149f81834654b47904e72c5c3760b8bc874c90b355628927ffca3bc17ce5/merged/home/app/app`.

```
1.4G    core.20715
1.1G    core.20746
709M    core.24489
384M    core.14116
379M    core.26810
364M    core.20730
258M    core.32643
107M    node_modules
69M core.20722
100K    package-lock.json
```

What is the function of the core file, can I remove those files and how to prevent generate those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general core files are generated when a program crashes/stops abnormally. It contains information about the program at he moment of crash such as data, stack traces, registers etc. One can use this for debugging the program. You can limit the size of the core file generated by using following

```sh
docker run --ulimit core=size
```

Follow the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit) on using `ulimit` flag

You can perform some cleanup using following. This will not remove your active volume and containers.

```sh
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
docker system prune --all --volumes --force
```

to remove all unused images, network,volumes.

Also delete the docker logs

```
find /var/lib/docker/containers/ -type f -name “
```

"*.log" -delete

then restart the docker service.
Reference [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/some-way-to-clean-up-identify-contents-of-var-lib-docker-overlay/30604)

Comment: The typeset quotes `“*.log”` will likely cause your command to fail. You should probably cite the website you lifted it from.

Comment: @asolanki , I also need to change “*.log” to "*.log". It works then

Answer (score -3):

for running dockers .. You can actually get into the docker the remove the older core.xxxx files . they are generally there for analysis . And no application breaks due to you deleting.